# Mobile app and server

Tags: android, server

Im writing an android app and need to get data from a server.
How can I know if there changes in the data whithout downloading all data every time ?

Do you think relying on date and time will work? I mean:
if the server tells apps last time updated was at 11.00
and current time is 11.01 this means there are updates { servers also tells me specifically what updates have been made
}
else no updates

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pending intent along with alarm manager and broadcast receiver to achieve this functionality.

For instance you can you can send a simple request say "Request A" to get a response from the server. On the server side if data has changed the response will be "true" else "false".

Now if you get the response as false, no need to download the complete data. If the response is true, the app should start downloading the data and then refresh the content.

You can set your Pending intent to fire after say "four hours". So after four hours the request will be sent and you will receive the response. Secondly, you 'll have to set Alarm manager and set it repeating, so that it sends the request after every four hours.

You will also need a Broadcast Receiver to receive the broadcast. In the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver you need to check the response and depending on it you need to refresh your data (if it is true).

Method to fire the pending intent every four hours :

```
public void scheduleAlarmForDataDownload() {
        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+1000 * 60 * 60 * 4;// current time + 4 Hrs
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent intentAlarm  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4, intentAlarm);// 4 Hrs
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for 4 Hrs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

AlarmReceiver class

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // method to send a request(Request A) to server and check the response.
        // If response is true again make a request to download and refresh the app data.
        // If the response is false do nothing

    }
```